# Is it safe to leave mint leaves in unrefrigerated in water overnight?

Tags: herbs, drinks

Instead of drinking plain water, I would like to start drinking water with mint. I plan to put several leaves of mint in a 1.5 liter bottle filled with tap water during the night, and drink the water during the following day.

So I would like to know, is it safe to leave the bottle un-refrigerated during the night?

Comment: Sorry, but health questions are off-topic here. The safety question is fine, though.

Comment: Is it necessary to leave it un-refrigerated?

Comment: It is more convenient since my refrigerator is already stuffed..

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59766/how-long-is-mint-infused-water-safe-to-drink?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you drink the herbal water the next day, no significant decomposition will have occurred so it should be perfectly safe, healthful and tasty. I would first wash the plant material to minimize any bacteria and chemical contaminants leeching into the water.

Answer (score 2):

To slow decomposition of the leaves, I would suggest adding some ice, and using a thermally insulated container for this.  However, a single night should be fine for the leaves overall.